# using single input textfield how to create functions like addidtion & substraction and display result in it?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

i have created a calculator. Now i want to add which can do operation like addition and multiplication.

I'm new to Javascript please anyone can hep me out. I have provided my code here, i'm trying it with event handler. I wanna make it as simple as possible. Please someone help me thanks.

I'm trying this from week please do help with proper examples. Thanks a lot in advance.
if it is possible then please give me an example. Simply i wanna create two functions which can do operations of multiplication and addition using event handlers but not with the two text field my calculator contain one text field so only with one and displays in that same text field.

Refer code:

```js
/*var temp;
    function onload() {
        temp = document.getElementById('new');
    }
    function ce(){
        var tempo = temp.slice(0, -1);
        document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = tempo;
    }
*/

/*$(document).ready(function()
{
       var temp = $('#new');
       var ce = $('#ce');
       ce.click(function() {
           alert(temp.val());
       });
   }); */

//var input1=0;
//var input2=0;
// textInputVal= parseInt(document.getElementById('new').value);



function one() {
  document.getElementById('new').value += 1;
}

function two() {
  document.getElementById('new').value += 2;
}

function three() {
  document.getElementById('new').value += 3;
}

function four() {
  document.getElementById('new').value += 4;
}

function five() {
  document.getElementById('new').value += 5;
}

function six() {
  document.getElementById('new').value += 6;
}

function seven() {
  document.getElementById('new').value += 7;
}

function eight() {
  document.getElementById('new').value += 8;
}

function nine() {
  document.getElementById('new').value += 9;
}

function zero() {
  document.getElementById('new').value += 0;
}

function actionevent() {
  var btn = document.getElementById("plu");
  onclick.btn = function() {
    textInputVal =
  }

}

function ce() {
  var textInputVal = 0,
    temp = 0;
  textInputVal = document.getElementById('new').value;
  //console.log(textInputVal);
  temp = textInputVal.slice(0, -1);
  //console.log(temp);
  document.getElementById('new').value = temp;
}
var demo = 0;

function mplus() {
  var textInputVal = 0;
  textInputVal = parseInt(document.getElementById('new').value);
  console.log(textInputVal);
  demo += textInputVal;
  console.log(demo);

}
var temp = 0;


//var textInputval;
function plus() {

  //var textInputval=0;
  //var textInputval1=0;

  var textInputval = parseInt(document.getElementById('new').value);
  console.log(textInputval);
  return textInputval;

  //document.getElementById("new").value=" ";
  //var temp = parseInt(document.getElementById('new').value);
  //textInputval1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('new').value);
  //temp = textInputval + textInputval1;
  //console.log(temp);
  //textInputval = $(this).val();
  //$(this).val('');
  //console.log(textInputval1);
}

function mminus() {
  var textInputVal = 0;
  textInputVal = parseInt(document.getElementById('new').value);
  console.log(textInputVal);
  demo -= textInputVal;
  console.log(demo);
}

function mr() {
  document.getElementById('new').value = demo;
}


/* $(document).ready (function(){

$("#clear_li").click(function(){
  $("li:last").remove();
});

}); */
//var inputval=innerHTML  - substring;
//var inputval=input.innerHTML;
//var sillyString = inputval.slice(0, -1);
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="cal-container">
    <form name="calculator">
      <input type="text" name="answer" value="" id="new">
      <br>
      <input type="button" value=" 1 " onclick="one()" />
      <input type="button" value=" 2 " onclick="two()" />
      <input type="button" value=" 3 " onclick="three()" />
      <input type="button" id="plu" value=" + " onclick="plus()" />
      <br>
      <input type="button" value=" 4 " onclick="four()" />
      <input type="button" value=" 5 " onclick="five()" />
      <input type="button" value=" 6 " onclick="six()" />
      <input type="button" value=" - " onclick="minus()" />
      <br>
      <input type="button" value=" 7 " onclick="seven()" />
      <input type="button" value=" 8 " onclick="eight()" />
      <input type="button" value=" 9 " onclick="nine()" />
      <input type="button" value=" * " onclick="multi()" />
      <br>
      <input type="button" value=" c " onclick="calculator.answer.value = ''" />
      <input type="button" value=" 0 " onclick="zero()" />
      <input type="button" value=" = " onclick="equal()" />
      <input type="button" value=" / " onclick="div()" />
      <br>
      <input type="button" value="CE" onclick="ce()" />
      <input type="button" value="M+" onclick="mplus()" />
      <input type="button" value="M-" onclick="mminus()" />
      <input type="button" value="mr" onclick="mr()" />
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: my code link :- https://jsfiddle.net/archan/usLhu9aa/

Comment: Check this http://www.siteforinfotech.com/2015/02/how-to-create-simple-calculator-using.html

Comment: mate i have already tried that now i don't want use that again. i wanna make that possible using event handlers or calling through onclick="fun()" so how i do that?

Comment: using event handlers or addeventlisteners how to do this using my posted html ? please guys help me out

Comment: I have editted the answer adding eventListeners.

Answer (score 0):

There were few errors in your code I changed them.I have only created for addition,subtraction,multiplication and division.Rest of them you can follow the same way I have done and get the result.

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/54mbtrkj/)

Here is the code.

```js
var one = function() {
  document.getElementById('new').value += 1;
}
var two = function() {
  document.getElementById('new').value += 2;
}
var three = function() {
  document.getElementById('new').value += 3;
}
var four = function() {
  document.getElementById('new').value += 4;
}
var five = function() {
  document.getElementById('new').value += 5;
}
var six = function() {
  document.getElementById('new').value += 6;
}
var seven = function() {
  document.getElementById('new').value += 7;
}
var one = function() {
  document.getElementById('new').value += 1;
}
var two = function() {
  document.getElementById('new').value += 2;
}
var three = function() {
  document.getElementById('new').value += 3;
}
var four = function() {
  document.getElementById('new').value += 4;
}
var five = function() {
  document.getElementById('new').value += 5;
}
var six = function() {
  document.getElementById('new').value += 6;
}
var seven = function() {
  document.getElementById('new').value += 7;
}
var eight = function() {
  document.getElementById('new').value += 8;
}
var nine = function() {
  document.getElementById('new').value += 9;
}
var zero = function() {
  document.getElementById('new').value += 0;
}
var plus = function() {
  document.getElementById('new').value += "+";
}
var minus = function() {
  document.getElementById('new').value += "-";
}
var multi = function() {
  document.getElementById('new').value += "*";
}
var div = function() {
  document.getElementById('new').value += "/";
}
var equal = function() {
  document.getElementById('new').value = eval(document.getElementById('new').value);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="cal-container">
    <form name="calculator">
      <input type="text" name="answer" value="" id="new">
      <br>
      <input type="button" value=" 1 " onclick="one()" />
      <input type="button" value=" 2 " onclick="two()" />
      <input type="button" value=" 3 " onclick="three()" />
      <input type="button" id="plu" value=" + " onclick="plus()" />
      <br>
      <input type="button" value=" 4 " onclick="four()" />
      <input type="button" value=" 5 " onclick="five()" />
      <input type="button" value=" 6 " onclick="six()" />
      <input type="button" value=" - " onclick="minus()" />
      <br>
      <input type="button" value=" 7 " onclick="seven()" />
      <input type="button" value=" 8 " onclick="eight()" />
      <input type="button" value=" 9 " onclick="nine()" />
      <input type="button" value=" * " onclick="multi()" />
      <br>
      <input type="button" value=" c " onclick="calculator.answer.value = ''" />
      <input type="button" value=" 0 " onclick="zero()" />
      <input type="button" value=" = " onclick="equal()" />
      <input type="button" value=" / " onclick="div()" />


    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

I am not sure why are you looking for `eventListeners` however if you want to do by that method then in HTML you have to assign `ID` to each `button` and remove `onClick` event.

```
<input type="button" value=" 1 id="one" />
```

And in `JavaScript` you have to write as follows for each `button id`

```
document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("click", one_func);

var one_func= function() {
document.getElementById('new').value += 1;
}
```

As you see this code is longer then the previous and is not a good practice.So I recommend you to do by the method I have done before.

Comment: Thanks Shubham but that's the same which i used before only that is in function.please can someone show me that how can i do this by using Event handlers i really need help guys?

Comment: This code is written using onClick event.What else do you need.Try to be more specific.Are you looking for onclick= "one(this.value);".If the above answer is helpful then atleast you can upvote.